# Сколько прошло недель с начала года?

Tags: javascript, дата

Как узнать, сколько прошло недель с начала года ?
У меня пока такой код:

```js
let time = Date.parse('2018-00-01T00:00:00'); 

let date = new Date();
let now = date.getTime(); 

let result = now - time; 
result = result / (); 
alert(result);
```

Comment: А о каких неделях речь. Вы можете конечно поделить ваше значение на 7 дней, но технически это будет количество семидневок с начала года, они будут меняться на том дне недели с которого начался год. А неделю принято начинать в понедельник (или воскресенье в некоторых странах). Кроме того, возможно надо учесть, что если год начался в четверг и позже, то по календарю первые числа года относятся к неделе предыдущего года

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php

Comment: @KoVadim оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ